# Where to upload my new custom ShortCode in Separate .php file?

Tags: customization, shortcode

I wrote my first ShortCode in a file called: myShortCodes.php.

Does the add_shortcode go in the same PHP file as the ShortCode itself? 
Where do I upload it? How does WordPress know to look in my file?

I don't have to modify \wp_includes\shortcodes.php do I?

So far I have tried uploading myShortCodes.php to

1. wp-includes/myShortCodes.php
2. wp-content/themes/mytheme/skeleton/myShortCodes.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, special theme functionality (including shortcodes) should be placed in your theme's `functions.php` file, which is in the root of your **theme** folder.  If the code is less than a few dozen lines, it probably won't be worth creating a separate file (unless you just really want to organize your code that way).

So the shortcode functionality and the `add_shortcode()` call should be in functions.php.

Let's say you do want to separate it though.  You can include your `myShortCodes.php` file like this in your functions.php file:

```
require_once('myShortCodes.php');
```

And then you can have the code (including the `add_shortcode()` call) kept in `myShortCodes.php`.

It's recommended to **not** alter the WordPress core files (like wp-includes/shortcodes.php) or put anything in the wp-includes folder because then it's outside of your theme folder and any upgrades to the WP core will cause your changes to be lost.

Comment: Wouldn't that override the shortcode, if the theme gets updated and `function.php` is replaced? So I would either need to create a child theme or implement a custom plug-in that encapsulates my shortcode.

Comment: @user1438038 Yes, if the theme is managed and updated by a third party, you absolutely should implement customizations as a plugin or child theme. I was assuming he created his own theme.

Answer (score 0):

Your all your shortcode functions should either go in `functions.php` or a plugin file or be [`include`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)'d/[`require`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.require.php)'d from one of them.